# Typescript .forEach and for in behavior

Tags: javascript, typescript, loops

I made a [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFATjAtgdRlAFgMThQFEBDCXACjgCMArALkVLAE8BKJl1xAbwChEQxDGCJq9RAEIAvDMRgQAGyWIAZGuSsADgFM4Y2nURz5AciO7oZ9n0HCHAeXpWoAOgDWu1gGcJddjdgIjIKSlBIWARxbRQ4bVsBB2ThAHpUkTE8XURY%20N0UKB4YH2YkS2hkNHQRKHsUh1FxIr0DRCMAbTztAF0TOUQLF2tE%20oaUlF0oEBQkVAxsPEIScipO7p72AG4x8YBffl2G9Mzas1LSRB95sABzREn0OAA3HJpdW5gkFgATRF0wH8AO64HC6Hzacjgo4pJqUFr6Qz0LpxXr9czXNB3Gx2cbjdaovryAnxHpueboSjbGHJA77akOA4HfgRaDwObVRYEIgASTA-i4bE4ZR4SWEcKM0gGihU6k0CLaktMgwqUBxYpSwRQ4mepG13RE5XoozxaQyTWyuVRBSKIguRroriqGFqNMaYnhOkR7WRG3RKuGapNpuSk2ms2dWBw3JQfP8KNJDJDzJDiBOTRw52YVxu90eLzeHy%20ZT%20AOBoKg4MhEGhqbhCqRdATaOV51z6rdDRJLZ9TY25OqVJ2qbpDVHQiZhwgCGuiBocB%20rGWoVwJlxwgARKxdHqN0wAEwABgAjAAOAA0Yw3kzAUAA%20op0O8UHvEABWQ%20Xhwb2BQJS6V8N1TYQABUeRAgAZYgNy-TdSBAPAiEAgA5BBSHQADYKEDddB%20HAkKYDcACEIIAQRI0iYKvL4fl0AAPQCAAVECInliGQqjvxoGAaEAgBhcjSOQnkAGVOM3SZgEAo992PcTsIgUgoDkwjmNY9j5MQDdFKgfdAIAEQANX0-AeT4zSNx8OAMKMV9eC0nS9MI4QjJMsygL2LCtJYPUUFIVhXw6IChFc0zzPPbydxyFINx6fgDgpLll1WSh50XZKKGpfhpzAWc0qXXkkHkDUtO3XcDxPC8rxve9H2fV8Py8n8cH-QDgKEMDIOgpr4MQl9CNQsB0Mwq9cPw-qtIoiiLJo%20imJYtiOKa7jeMIgSiKE0SLMk6TD1kiydJUrS1MWg6lKcrTQvcpqrJs%20g7Ic862pC4ywo8nqhpQPyAqYIKXNe67ItIaLkli%20L%20ES6NljjfLobALKcqs-83CUOBbkoDcuUQZZEBXDdqURuBkdR9HYZCVZtjTDJSNlCkML%20HBECBIgPB8KcZyJ3QUbRjGsZxvl8Z2QniZ5snY3hrYhBOEDqkQOgQFnS1gBgFBZ1VRAGFSfggA) to show you the code and the output. I don't understand why I don't have the same result in my code when I'm using `.forEach` and `for in` loop.

I made 2 functions to trim all body parameters. The first function use `.forEach()` and the 2nd use `for in`.

Here is the functions:

```
function trimWithForEach(obj: any): any {
    if (obj !== null && typeof obj === 'object') {
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (prop) {
            // if the property is an object trim it
            if (typeof obj[prop] === 'object') {
                return trimWithForEach(obj[prop]);
            }

            // if it's a string remove begin and end whitespaces
            if (typeof obj[prop] === 'string') {
                obj[prop] = obj[prop].trim();
            }
        });
    }
}

function trimWithForIn(obj: any): any {
    if (obj !== null && typeof obj === 'object') {
        for (var prop in obj) {
            // if the property is an object trim it
            if (typeof obj[prop] === 'object') {
                return trimWithForIn(obj[prop]);
            }

            // if it's a string remove begin and end whitespaces
            if (typeof obj[prop] === 'string') {
                obj[prop] = obj[prop].trim();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With the `forEach()` I have the good result that I want, it will trim all my body. But with `for in` I have a problem because only the first `object` conditon is triggered to make my recursive call and if I have other object types they are ignored. The recursive call works only once in all my body object in the `for in` loop and I don't know why.

Can you help me to understand ?

Comment: `return` in a `forEach` callback does something completely different to it being on the same layer within a `for ... in` loop. I don't understand what you expect that `return` to do anyways. Also, `for ... in` iterates over prototypes, but while that's a difference, it's not the thing that breaks your code completely.

Comment: `forEach` accepts a callback function. When you `return` inside the `forEach`, you are returning from that callback function that was passed into `forEach`. Since `forEach`'s return is `undefined`, a return doesn't do anything. If your goal is to update each object, then do an assignment instead of the return; something like: `prop = trimWithForEach(obj[prop]);` Be cautious not to end up in an infinite loop, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `for..in` loop the `return` is returning you out of function at the very first time it encounters the condition to be true. That's why the later items never get processed.

I am not quite sure what you are trying to do here but there is a basic difference between the way 'forEach' and 'for...in' works with regards to 'return'.

In `for...in` `return` returns the value out of function, but in `forEach` the `return` doesn't work.

Look at the following simple example for more clarity

```
var testfn = function() {
  let a = [1,2,3]
  let b =  a.forEach(el => {
    if ( el == 2 )
      return el
  })
  console.log("Came here!")
  console.log({b})
}

var testfn1 = function() {
  let a = [1,2,3]
  for ( let i in a ){
    if ( a[i] == 2 )
      return a[i]
  }
  console.log("Came here!")
  console.log({a})
}
testfn()
testfn1()
```